# C# one tcp networkstream accepted

Tags: c#, tcp, listener, filestream, networkstream

I have an issue with a TCP Listener.
The scenario is the following:
 - I am receiving TCP packets (8192 Bytes each) and I would like to dump the data received from NetworkStream into a file (using FileStream);
 - What I saw is that all the TCP packets arrived to the TCP listener but only the first 8192 Bytes are dumped into the file.

I believe that the NetStream is faster than the IO operation to the file.
My code is:

```
    try
    {
        // Set TcpListener on port 8
        Int32 portN = 8;
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portN);

        // Start listening for client requests
        server.Start();
        Console.Write("Waiting for connection... ");

        // Define File Name
        string RcvFileName = @"c:\ethernet\out_file.raw";

        // Buffer for reading data
        int NrBytesRec;
        Byte[] RecData = new Byte[8192];

        // enter into listening loop
        while (true)
        {
            // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
            // You can also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            NetworkStream netstream = client.GetStream();

            // Append data into file
            FileStream fs_wr = new FileStream(RcvFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

            // Dump data
            while ((NrBytesRec = netstream.Read(RecData, 0, RecData.Length)) > 0)
            {
                fs_wr.Write(RecData, 0, NrBytesRec);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", NrBytesRec);
            }

            netstream.Close();
            fs_wr.Close();
            //client.Close();    
        }
```

Comment: Try emptying your `RecData` array after the call to `fs_wr.Write` as you've already written out the bytes and shouldn't need them anymore.

Comment: The code looks good. Debug the sender. It's not sending what you expect.

Comment: I just tested using the code you supplied: @usr is correct. It worked perfectly for me. Your sending is not sending what you expect.

Comment: Thanks! Did you tried with more than one TCP packet?